# PHP & jQuery - Change href depending on body class or scrolltop?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, class, href

I would like the onclick of the logo to scroll to the top (home page) if clicked from the home page (one page scroll website) and if on an internal page then the logo link to remain as the site url.

My client basically does not want the site to reload onclick of the logo from the home page.

What would be the best way to do this? I have thought of 2 ways so far...

1. Replace the href attribute with the url + body class (my menu links use this and scroll to each section without reloading the page)
2. If click on logo when body hasclass .home, scroll to the top of the window. But I'm not sure if this would override the url set by the theme?

This is a snippet of how the logo href is set from the partials/menus.php file...

```
$logoDiv = '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'">';
```

I am using the Uncode theme on Wordpress. And I am a newbie at PHP and jQuery... Just a suggestion as the best way to go about this would be greatly appreciated, and I can try and work through it myself!

Thank you :)

Comment: Dirty trick: Having an `href='#'` will scroll to the top without the need for JavaScript (unless you want to animate the scroll).

Comment: Ok great... so do you think I could use this with my first idea of replacing the href attribute using jquery? Maybe something like this...

    $(document).ready(function() {
 if($(body).hasClass("home")){
     $(".navbar-brand[href='http://ldngrp.co']").attr('href', '#')
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
$logoDiv = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);">';
```

Hope it may help you

Comment: Hi, thank you! So I could say in the php file... if: get_body_class 'home' then do your suggestion, else - the original functionality?

Comment: Yes, you should try once.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your current link is the homepage before rendering the page:

```
$href = ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]==home_url("","relative")?"#":esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ))

$logoDiv = '<a href="'.$href.'" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'">';
```

If you wish to animate the scroll then you can add the following jQuery:

```
$("[href='#']").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
     });
});
```

This would work on all links with `href='#'` if you want to limit it you'd need a more specific selector.

As your comment suggests, you can also do this with jQuery if you have a way to determine if your current page is the home-page.

Your solution should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($(body).hasClass("home")){ 
        $(".navbar-brand[href='ldngrp.co']").attr('href', '#'); 
     }
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the explanation... I will have a play around!

Comment: There's a chance that `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will append a `/` at the end while `home_url` would not, better check what `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` contains in the homepage first (or just use `trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]),"/")` instead

Comment: Hi! So I put the php in an if and else statement, and overriden the parent them file with a new file... Nothing has changed at all... This is the php code I used... 

    if($href =($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]==home_url("","relative")?"#":esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ))) {
 $logoDiv = '<a href="'.$href.'" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'">';
 } else {
 $logoDiv = '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'">';
}

Comment: Why did you put that in an `if else` statement?

Comment: I didn't at first, nothing happened, then I thought it would make sense to... Surely, you need to check if the url is homepage then set the href as #, else do what was originally there?

Comment: `$href` is set via an inline if so the check is supposed to be done there via `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]==home_url("","relative")` do check and compare `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` `home_url("","relative")` to ensure they are the same in the comepage, there may be slashes added.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand... So I would simply add the 2 PHP lines above    $logoDiv = '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'" class="navbar-brand" data-minheight="'.(($LOGO->logo_min == "") ? "20" : esc_attr($LOGO->logo_min)).'">';

Comment: To be honest, I don't actually know if the file override or the php isn't working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116792/discussion-between-apokryfos-and-user3541921).